# T-test vs. Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test vs. Bayes

Tags: probability, bayesian, statistical-significance, t-test

I am looking at a case where i have traffic to a page with say 10,000 visitors. About 2% of those visitors buy a product between $20-200. I want to test if a site redesign will increase my average revenue per visitor.

My first instinct is to run a t-test on the control and test to see what the p-value is.
Doing some research I found this page: https://www.blastanalytics.com/blog/best-revenue-significance-calculator-ab-testing

It says a Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test is needed due to the skewed distribution caused by most users not converting and buying a product. Is this a test I should be looking into using?

If so are there any power analysis tools I can use to determine the sample size?

Or are there any other tests you would recommend?
I have been looking into the Welch-t test as well.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have any data to keep up with visitors across site changes and days? If you aren't able to uniquely identify every individual and are just looking at the summary statistics (e.g., new N of buyers versus old N of buyers), then I'd expect that you're going to violate the independence assumptions of these methods since some people will be counted multiple times (e.g., 5 visits may all be one person and 2 separate purchases may be from that same person as well)

Comment: yes we can track who is in one vs the other and maintain 2 separate testing samples

Comment: In that case, you may just check whether a t-test and Wilcoxon U-Test give you different results and inspect which one is more appropriate. An alternative way to frame this question may be as a zero-inflated binomial regression where you're predicting who make no purchases vs those who make purchases of increasingly expensive brackets. You can use a multilevel model to include people multiple times, and add an indicator variable for pre- vs post-redesign. Just depends on what question you have and how you'll want to use the model/data

Comment: Hi @Billy I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!  I have been thinking the same thing, to run both and see the results then decide how to move forward. I am also thinking of throwing a Bayes model in there, I like using them to see another side to things for perspective. The zero-inflated binomial regression is very interesting as well, I will look into that!